# Benchmark tests for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I would like to do some comparison between different boards and architectures (arm/ia32) in terms of usage node.js.
Can anyone point to me to a set of relevant benchmark tests that make usage of node.js, if there are any?

I am not looking for general JavaScript benchmarks tests, but something that is node.js related and specific.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find any good benchmarks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could always use `ab` (a part of the `apache-utils` package) to benchmark the file served by node and make concurrent requests.

```
$ ab http://example.com/client.html/ -n 10000 -c 1000
```

This would test with a 1000 concurrent connections and a total of 10000 connections.

Here are a [couple](http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-node-js-testing-performance-against-apache-php/) [of](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/17/performance-benchmarking-the-node-js-backend-of-our-48h-product-wehearvoices-net/) blog posts you may find interesting if you decide to go ahead with `ab`